# Argument '*' is not a function on AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

Adding `ng-controller` on view causing `Error: [ng:areq] Argument 'ValidationCtrl' is not a function, got undefined`. Following are the code snippets:

profile.html

```
<div class="row" ng-controller="ValidationCtrl">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label class="control-label">First Name</label>
          <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your first name" class="form-control" name="firstname" ng-model="user.first_name">
          <span class="error text-small block" ng-if="Form.first_name.$dirty && Form.first_name.$invalid">Last Name is required</span>
          <span class="success text-small" ng-if="Form.first_name.$valid">Wonderful!</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

app.js

```
    var myApp = angular.module("MyApp",['ngResource','ngRoute','ui.router','ngMessages','ngResource','cfp.loadingBar','duScroll','ngAnimate','satellizer','pascalprecht.translate','ngCookies','oc.lazyLoad','ui.bootstrap','toastr'])
        .config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider','$authProvider','$ocLazyLoadProvider','JS_REQUIRES',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$authProvider,$ocLazyLoadProvider,jsRequires){
            $stateProvider
               .state('app.profile', {
                    url: '/profile',
                    templateUrl: "views/profile.html",
                    title: 'Buttons',
                    resolve: loadSequence('flow','validationCtrl')
                });

$ocLazyLoadProvider.config({
            debug: false,
            events: true,
            modules: jsRequires.modules
        });

function loadSequence() {
        var _args = arguments;
        return {
            deps: ['$ocLazyLoad', '$q',
            function ($ocLL, $q) {
                var promise = $q.when(1);
                for (var i = 0, len = _args.length; i < len; i++) {
                    promise = promiseThen(_args[i]);
                }
                return promise;

                function promiseThen(_arg) {
                    if (typeof _arg == 'function')
                        return promise.then(_arg);
                    else
                        return promise.then(function () {
                            var nowLoad = requiredData(_arg);
                            if (!nowLoad)
                                return $.error('Route resolve: Bad resource name [' + _arg + ']');
                            return $ocLL.load(nowLoad);
                        });
                }

                function requiredData(name) {
                    if (jsRequires.modules)
                        for (var m in jsRequires.modules)
                            if (jsRequires.modules[m].name && jsRequires.modules[m].name === name)
                                return jsRequires.modules[m];
                    return jsRequires.scripts && jsRequires.scripts[name];
                }
            }]
        };
    }
}]);
```

validationCtrl.js

```
'use strict';
/** 
  * controller for Validation Form example
*/
myApp.controller('ValidationCtrl', ["$scope", "$state", "$timeout", "SweetAlert", function ($scope, $state, $timeout, SweetAlert) {
    alert('validation');
    $scope.master = $scope.myModel;
    $scope.form = {

        submit: function (form) {
            var firstError = null;
            if (form.$invalid) {

                var field = null, firstError = null;
                for (field in form) {
                    if (field[0] != '$') {
                        if (firstError === null && !form[field].$valid) {
                            firstError = form[field].$name;
                        }

                        if (form[field].$pristine) {
                            form[field].$dirty = true;
                        }
                    }
                }

                angular.element('.ng-invalid[name=' + firstError + ']').focus();
                SweetAlert.swal("The form cannot be submitted because it contains validation errors!", "Errors are marked with a red, dashed border!", "error");
                return;

            } else {
                SweetAlert.swal("Good job!", "Your form is ready to be submitted!", "success");
                //your code for submit
            }

        },
        reset: function (form) {

            $scope.myModel = angular.copy($scope.master);
            form.$setPristine(true);

        }
    };

}]);
```

and my config.constant.js

```
myApp.constant('JS_REQUIRES', {

scripts: {
 'validationCtrl': ['controllers/validationCtrl.js']
}});
```

Thanks!

Comment: Check whether validationCtrl.js file is loaded using developer tools